# Trim range with evaluate

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to speed up trimming a data sheet with about 5000 rows and 12 columns.

I used a *For Each* Loop that works but sets Excel into "not responding" for a while before it is done.

I researched and found *With* and *Evaluate* apparently work faster. For me it ends up deleting a bunch of my data and resorting the rest of it.

Here is my old code that works but is slow:

```
'trim everything in range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = timeSheet.Range("A2:L" & lastCell)
    For Each cell In Rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Value = Trim(cell)
        End If
    Next cell
```

This is my new code that is fast but destroys my data:

```
'trim everything in range 2.0
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = timeSheet.Range("A2:L" & lastCell)
    With Rng
        .Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & .Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & .Address & ")))")
    End With
```

What is wrong with my second code or ideas on how I can speed up the first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the values in an array, so the Trim() there, then put back the values.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim Rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long, arr, v
    Set Rng = timeSheet.Range("A2:L" & lastCell)
    arr = Rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        v = arr(r, c)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then arr(r, c) = Trim(v)
    Next c
    Next r
    Rng.Value = arr
End Sub
```